# Some questions about velodyne_pointcloud package

Tags: ros, velodyne-pointcloud, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am learning ROS recently . I have some questions about velodyne package:

1. After I run
   "$roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud 32e_points.launch calibration:=/home/llm/catkin_ws/src/velodyne_pointcloud/params/32db.yaml"
   in the terminal , which .cpp file in src/conversions/ was executed ?
2. I notice that in the file convert.cpp , "output_" publish a "outMsg" (velodyne_rawdata::VPointtCloud::Ptr)  in line 78,but in line 31 ,the "output_" advertise "sensor_msgs::PointCloud2" message ,I can not understand this code.
3. I am focused on this one . I created a node to subscribe the topic "velodyne_points" , and I want to extract the information of the points's XYZ coordinate value from the topic , but I can not understand the message type "sensor::PointCloud2", what should I do?

Looking for you reply ! Thank you very much !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/188725/some-questions-about-velodyne_pointcloud-package/) by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2014-08-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. That launch file runs the cloud nodelet in a velodyne_nodelet manager process. The [cloud nodelet is built](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_pointcloud/src/conversions/CMakeLists.txt#L7) using [cloud_nodelet](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_pointcloud/src/conversions/cloud_nodelet.cc).cc and [convert.cc](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_pointcloud/src/conversions/convert.cc).
2. The constructor must advertise the topic before the callback can publish to it.
3. An example of reading the individual points in the message is here in [RingColors::convertPoints](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/blob/master/velodyne_pointcloud/src/conversions/colors.cc#L63), a method that reads /velodyne_points and publishes a colored cloud containing the same points in /velodyne_rings.

**EDIT**: To run the Ring Colors nodelet, you can create your own launch file, something like this (*untested*):

```
<include file="$(find velodyne_pointcloud)/launch/32e_points.launch" />
<node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="ring_colors_nodelet"
      args="load velodyne_pointcloud/RingColorsNodelet velodyne_nodelet_manager" />
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2014-08-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on 2014-08-04**:
Thank you .

1. For the second question , I mean that the "outMsg" is not a type "sensor_msgs::PointCloud2" message . In my previous study , I noticed that the types should be same like the code(copied from the tutorials) listed :
   {
   ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::String>("chatter", 1000);
   ...
   std_msgs::String msg;
   ...
   chatter_pub.publish(msg);
   }
2. For the third question. If I want to run the ringcolors_nodelet.cc and colors.cc and read the point's message , should I creat a .launch file like the cloud_nodelet.launch and add it to 32e_points.launch?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-08-04**:
pcl_ros and pcl_conversions provide a callback interface for the PointCloud2 message, converting it to a PCL point cloud, which the code can conveniently manipulate.

**Comment by [Lau](https://answers.ros.org/users/19913/lau/) on 2014-08-04**:
Thank you ! now I can read the individual point now !

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-08-05**:
If this answers your question, please click the check mark.